# IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) U-203.6682.168 - Cannot resolve symbol - Java classes

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

After update to IDEA 2020.3.1, some of my projects cannot be built successfully in the IDE.

I'm getting

> Cannot resolve symbol ''

for classes defined by me. All classes from dependencies are loaded OK.

I'm using gradle wrapper and I've tried several things to fix this issue without results:

1. Reinstalled Intellij Idea.
   Deleted local folder in AppData\Roaming\Jetbrains...\IntellijIdea2020.3
2. Cache Invalidation from the IDE
3. Deleted .gradle folder with all cached dependencies
4. Deleted project and download again from git repo.
5. Rollback to different (older version of IDE) 2020.2.x

Project is built successfully with `gradlew clean build`.
The only problem is that the IDE cannot find the classes.
Some of my projects are OK, but others are not.

Comment: Have you checked the project structure (File -> Project Structure -> Modules)? Source folders e.g. src/main/java should be marked as such with a blue folder icon.  If it's not, you can configure it manually from that screen. I've found sometime importing maven and gradle projects, IntelliJ doesn't set the structure up correctly

Comment: Anything to see in console log? ( https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files )

Comment: Show the screenshot with the error you see. Can you build the project (Build | Rebuild Project action)?

Comment: Where the class is defined which is not found - in same module or in a different module?

Comment: Thank you for all comments. Finally I've deleted everything Intellij, Projects, Git , Gradle etc... restart and after all of this, my projects are finally green.  I thank that this issue was due to some security tools installed on my laptop which are can cached some information and scan files etc..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (Intellij 2020.3.3) and solved by invalidating caches of Intellij (File | Invalidate Caches / Restart)